# What is the format of an AARRGGBB array?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to create an Image using a red, a green, and a blue value and to create a RGBImage you need to provide an int[] in the form of an AARRGGBB array. What does the format of an AARRGGBB array look like? By format I mean {red, green, blue}?

Comment: Best-guess is that the acronym refers to *(Alpha,* Red, Green, Blue), where each of these four items (in the range *0-255* == *$00-FF)* occupies one byte in a four-byte *(32-bit)* integer value.  Such that *(Alpha=1, Red=2, Green=3, Blue=4)* would be encoded *(using hexadecimal notation):* `$01020304`.  *Alpha,* of course, referring to the *transparency* of the pixel, such that `$00` is completely transparent, and `$FF` *(decimal 255)* is completely opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@mike-robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811873/mike-robinson) mentioned in the comment this is a pretty standard notion. A Java `int` includes 4 bytes of data the MSB (most significant byte) is the alpha follower by the red, blue and green for the LSB (least significant byte).

So to set an AARRGGBB int just use something like:

```
int aarrggbbVal = ((0xff000000 & (alpha << 24)) | 
         ((0xff0000 & (red << 16)) |
         ((0xff00 & (green << 8)) |
         (0xff & blue);
```